# Using MIT license for commercial purpose

Tags: mit, github

I am interested in using this (https://github.com/awaragi/prometheus-mssql-exporter) software within our organisation. This repository has an MIT license.
I would like to clone this repository to my organisation git and also make some modifications to the code.
Can I do so without breaking any licensing agreements? (I am not sure if this has been asked before, could find it.) Thank you helping me.

Comment: The MIT license is very straightforward. What exactly are you not sure about?

Comment: @curiousdannii, that can I copy the code and save in a private repository without violating the MIT license.

Comment: You may distribute any software under any open source license commercially... You just have to fulfill the obligations described in the license.what those are varies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MIT license does not restrict you for your usecase. As you may refer the license wordings:

> Copyright © 2020
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
> a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
> “Software”), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
> without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
> distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
> permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
> the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
> included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED “AS IS”, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
> EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
> MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
> IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
> CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
> TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
> SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

Source: [MIT License](https://mit-license.org/)